# Powershell variable assignment inside a dockerfile and modification

Tags: docker, powershell, dockerfile

I made use of a powershell script to download a file from an external repository as follows:

```
$user='XXXX'
$password='XXXXX'
$secpassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($user,$secpassword)
$path = [Environment]::GetFolderPath("MyDocuments")
wget -Uri https://XXXX/file.zip -Credential $credential -Outfile "$path\temp.zip"
```

The above script worked fine and I was able to download the zip on to my local.

My aim is to have this script inside a dockerfile, so I can build a docker image.
But when I do so with the following script, I get the following error :

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019
RUN echo -e hello from the image

##Powershell commands
RUN $USER='XX'
RUN $PASS='XX'
RUN $SECPASS = ConvertTo-SecureString $PASS -AsPlainText -Force ##ERROR

RUN echo -e after everything
```

Error:

[image: Error]

Any insights as to what am I doing wrong?

Comment: First off, every `RUN` command happens in its *own* shell session, meaning any variables you set simply don't persist across commands. Second, you presumably you want these values to be settable *outside* the container -- use `ENV` for that and access the values with `$env:name` in PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

In the `Dockerfile`, we can use `ENV` to declare environment variables, and refer them in the powershell commands, like below.

```
ENV key=value
RUN echo $env:key
```

*Eg.*:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019
# Using powershell shell 
SHELL ["powershell", "-NoProfile", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"] 
# Powershell commands
ENV USER="user1"
ENV PASS="pass1"
RUN echo "1 - $USER and $PASS"
RUN echo "2 - $env:USER and $env:PASS"
```

Output for command `RUN echo "1 - $USER and $PASS"`:

```
1
-
and
```

Output for command `RUN echo "2 - $env:USER and $env:PASS"`:

```
2
-
user1
and
pass1
```

Credits to `@jeroen-mostert`'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75147954/powershell-variable-assignment-inside-a-dockerfile-and-modification#comment132611107_75147954).